# Why can't I use std::optional with Boost Asio sockets without moving them

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm creating a simple network game in c++.
I have a server class where a single socket is stored for usage. The socket is not known at the creation of the class, so I've chosen to use a `std::optional<tcp::socket>` (is this the correct way or is there a better one?) which is initialized to `std::nullopt` and later a socket will have a socket stored inside.
I've seen that, since it only has a rvalue copy operator, I have to move the socket before assigning it, in this way:

```
std::optional<tcp::socket> optSocket(std::nullopt);
....
optSocket = std::move(mySocket);
```

On the other hand, I've seen that if I use a simple "std::string" variable (so not a primitive type) I don't need to move it and I can simply do a copy assignment:

```
std::optional<std::string> optString(std::nullopt);
....
optString = myString;
```

While, if I try to do the same with a socket, it gives me the following error:

```
No viable overloaded '=' 
candidate template ignored: requirement '__and_v<std::__not_<std::is_same<std::optional<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio 
::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor>>, 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost:... 
candidate template ignored: could not match 'optional' against 'basic_stream_socket' 
candidate template ignored: could not match 'optional' against 'basic_stream_socket'
```

Why is there a difference between the two types, and why do i need to move the socket (or any other object to pass it to an std::optional)? Wouldn't it be better to have both a copy and move assignment?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What should happen when you make a copy of a socket and then use both of them separately? What when you close one of them and keep using the other?  Most answers to these questions lead you to `std::shared_ptr<socket>`

Comment: The answer is correct. If you really want to duplicate a socket, in windows there is WSADuplicateSocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, sockets aren't copyable because it's not clear what a copy of a socket would *be*.  When the remote end sends data which socket instance would receive that data; the original or the copy?  What happens when you close the original what should happen to the copy?  You could design a `socket` class that acts as a shared handle to a socket instead of representing the socket itself, but that would go against the general design theory that most C++ objects follow.  That's what something like `std::shared_ptr` is for.

Something as simple as a string doesn't have most of these sorts of concerns.  It's fairly clear what it means to make a copy of a string: you just copy the bytes that represent the characters in the string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you, just for learning purposes, what part of code specifies this characteristic (that a socket is not copyable but a string or other objects could be)?

Comment: @Andrea A type is non-copyable if it defines a move constructor and/or move assignment operator but no copy constructor and/or copy assignment operator.  Or if it declares the copy constructor and assignment operator as `delete`d.